# I am struck in setting state using spread operator in setState

Tags: reactjs, setstate, spread

I have a object consisting of a and b.I am initializing this in a state with value formValue.When I tried to set state for b using setState I wrote below, I am getting parsing error and expected ,.What am I doing wrong here?

```
form:{
a:"",
b:[],
}
const [state,setState]=useState({
formValue:form
})
setState({...state,formValue.b:some array})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have an issue in your setState, you can't have formValue.b as key.
"formValue.b" would be possible by the way.

But for your issue, I think you are looking for:

```
setState({...state,formValue: {...state.formValue, b: [] }})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not beautiful but works for me:

```
const newState = [...this.state.form]
newState.b = newArray
this.setState({form: newState})
```